# How to sum fields in a view Qweb?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I am creating a report (qweb view) in the account.invoice model and wish to sum some fields for each invoice line as shown in the following image:

[image]

The problem is that not sum the fields as I want. What should I do?

```
cantidad_producto = fields.Integer(string='Cantidad Producto', store=True, readonly=True, compute='cantidad_consolidado')
total_precio_unitario = fields.Monetary(string='Total precio unitario', store=True, readonly=True, compute='cantidad_consolidado')
total_precio_neto = fields.Monetary(string='Total Cantidad Producto', store=True, readonly=True, compute='cantidad_consolidado')
```

And this is my function compute in the file account.invoice.py:

```
@api.one
@api.depends('invoice_line_ids.quantity', 'invoice_line_ids.price_unit', 'invoice_line_ids.price_subtotal')
def cantidad_consolidado(self):
    self.cantidad_producto = sum(line.quantity for line in self.invoice_line_ids)
    self.total_precio_unitario = sum(line.price_unit for line in self.invoice_line_ids)
    self.total_precio_neto = sum(line.price_subtotal for line in self.invoice_line_ids
```

And finally, this is my view code:

```
<p>Resumen</p>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center">Total Cantidad</th>
      <th class="text-center">Total Precio Unitario</th>
      <th class="text-center">Total Precio(Neto)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="invoice_tbody">
    <td class="text-center">
      <span t-esc="cantidad_producto" />
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <span t-esc="total_precio_unitario" />
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <span t-esc="total_precio_neto" />
    </td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Why do not sum the fields in the report? Someone could tell me and so help me Please.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define one class which is inherited from **report_sxw.rml_parse** class, in that class you need to define **init** method where you need to add your **method name** as **KEY** of **localcontext** dictionary.

```
class sale_quotation_report(report_sxw.rml_parse):

    def __init__(self, cr, uid, name, context): 
        super(sale_quotation_report, self).__init__(cr, uid, name, context=context)
            self.localcontext.update({
                    ‘get_total’: self._get_total,
            })

    def _get_total(self, lines, field):
        total = 0.0
        for line in lines :
            total += line.product_uom_qty or 0.0
        return total
```

One more class need to be defined which is inherited from **osv.AbstractModel**

```
class report_saleorderqweb(osv.AbstractModel):
    _name = ‘module_name.report_sale_order_qweb’
    _inherit = ‘report.abstract_report’
    _template = ‘module_name.report_sale_order_qweb’
    _wrapped_report_class = sale_quotation_report

Here,

_name = ‘report.<module_name>.<report_name>’
_inherit = ‘report.abstract_report’
_template = ‘<module_name>.<report_name>’
_wrapped_report_class = <parser_class_name>
```

And finally call that method from template

```
<t t-foreach=”docs” t-as=”o”>
    <span t-esc=”get_total(o.order_line)”/>
</t>
```

You can refer [Steps to create Qweb report](http://blog.emiprotechnologies.com/create-qweb-report-odoo/)

Comment: The link is no longer available.